# Creating file with PPID

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x

On Linux, I'm trying to create a file with the PID on its name with python, I know on bash is possible like this:

```
outfile=/tmp/saul.$$.tmp
```

And then I can just redirect the output to that variable:

```
echo "Hello World" >> $outfile
```

I tried this in python:

```
log="/home/ss055g/log_$$.log"
f=open(log,'w')
f.write("Esto es una prueba")
f.close()
```

And it did not work. The log it created was: log_$$.log, my question is, how can I add the pid to the log instead of the $$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
import os
pid = os.getpid()
log_file="/home/ss055g/log_%s.log" % pid
f=open(log_file,'w')
f.write("Esto es una prueba")
f.close()
```